# Feel that this is not my job

Tags: new-job

This is the second job in my career where I was told that I am being brought on to help the team that's overloaded with too much work. 2 weeks into the job, I am getting strong vibes that my role is not what I am meant to be doing and instead I should be partnering/assisting other colleagues. 
There is no concrete evidence, just strong vibes. I feel like my relationships are slowly deteriorating because of this as well.
What should I do, how should I approach this?

Comment: Voting to close because I have no clue what you are talking about.  Redirect your question to someone who has a crystal ball and who can read your mind.

Comment: "My role is not what I am meant to be doing" - huh?  Do you mean that what you've been told is different from what the overloaded team has been told?  Isn't the whole point of helping an overloaded team to partner & assist those colleagues?

Comment: I've read this 3 times and can't figure out what you're talking about.  You're going to have to put some context into this before anyone can give you anything useful.

Comment: "I feel like my relationships are slowly deteriorating" - what relationships? With your colleagues, or your personal relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Talk to your manager.**

Generally, 2 weeks into a new job is too early to decide if it is "not for you". Ask your manager what his plans are for you, because only he can tell you where he sees you fit in the bigger picture. Maybe he wants to move you into such a "partnering" role, but cannot do it right away due to some constraints. Unless you ask, you cannot know.

If you realize that he doesn't really have a concrete plan for you, or his plan doesn't excite you, then tell him the kind of work you would love to do, and ask him if he can assign you something like that. Be prepared to hear "OK, I will consider it", "Not right now, maybe a few months later", or even a "No".

Beyond that point, it is up to you how long you are willing to wait for changes to happen. If you don't find an "exciting" role coming up soon enough to your liking, you could look for another job where you *might*.